# Laravel how can I delete the whole app upon the call of an api?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm doing a project as freelancing and it has been a month and I want to make sure I will get paid once the project is finish. I would like to guarantee that the whole website is deleted or just the views folder and controllers and assets. I know this sounds a bit malicious but it's my first freelancing job and I am scared I have been wasting my time. The project is hosted on the client online shared host and I constantly update it. Anyone know what can I do?

Comment: Upload somewhere until you got approved/paid, then give the password and/or code to the client. You need a contract. Anyway, this is too broad for stackoverflow.

Comment: Perhaps is true but at this point a bit late and I didn't realize before. My only option is really just make the website inaccessible through code

Comment: how would your deletion code execute? you can probably write a bash cron to delete files. But make sure you have a backup of the project in case they tell you to revert.

Comment: @MalcolmInTheCenter think it's not too hard, just send a request to some hidden endpoint to reset the cron job counter

Comment: Interesting question. I'd go for the `routes/web.php` file. Create a web2.php, an unreachable route in web.php and an artisan command. That route triggers the command that deletes web.php and renames web2.php to web.php where all links route to an 'under construction' page. Anybody who knows Laravel can reverse engineer a lot. But not the routes. Good luck with that one!

Comment: Ask 50% before typing any code, and 50% the day before you deploy the project to production. Make a contract with these terms with the client. I'm working 10+ years as a freelancer getting paid every single time. That malicious client will probably not agree with these terms.

Comment: @JonathanMartins I will do this next time. Thanks for the tips

Answer (score -1):

You can create an admin user for yourself behind the scenes, I main not in the database table, just save the username and password in a file and check special condition for that specific user, Then you can login to the system by that username and password, then in somewhere create a query by running that query first get a backup of database and then drop the database.